# How to make properties private?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, properties

Someone told me I could make properties private so that only an instance of the class can refer to them (via self.)

However, if I use @private in the class interface and then declare the property normally, it can still be accessed from outside of the class... So how can I make properties private? Syntax example please.

Answer (score 21):

You need to include these properties in a class extension.  This allows you to define properties (and more recently iVars) within your implementation file in an interface declaration.  It is similar to defining a category but without a name between the parentheses.

So if this is your MyClass.m file:

```
// Class Extension Definition in the implementation file
@interface MyClass()

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *myString; 

@end

@implementation MyClass

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if( self )
    {
        // This property can only be accessed within the class
        self.myString = @"Hello!";
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: Note that the class extension can be in a header file that you #import only in the classes that need access, thus effectively allowing a "library private" property.

Answer (score 5):

Declare the property in the implementation (.m) file, like so:

```
@interface MyClass()

@property (nonatomic, retain) MyPrivateClass *secretProperty;

@end
```

You'll be able to use that property within your class without a compiler warning.

Comment: What is the advantage of creating property there.We can directly use ivar.Is there any?

Comment: The advantages are consistency (public and private properties are accessed in the same way), clarity (properties look like properties) and flexibility (all property access goes through the same method, so lazy loading, computed properties, etc. are all trivial).